# Preview de imagem

Tags: javascript, html, imagem

Estou fazendo um preview, e esta acontecendo assim, eu quero que não aparece nada como se nao tivesse imagem, e somente aparecesse a imagem do preview quando o usuário escolhesse a imagem.

Esta ficando assim antes de colocar a imagem, porém eu quero q nao tenha essa forma sem imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

JavaScript

```
var loadFile = function(event) {
     var output = document.getElementById('output');
     output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
}
```

Html que pega a imagem e mostra

```
<img id="output" style="width:100%;height:250px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="file" name="img" id="img" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" onchange="loadFile(event)"/>
<br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode deixar a imagem sem opacidade, adicionando `opacity: 0` ao style:

```
<img src="sem-imagem.jpg" id="output" style="opacity: 0; width:100%;height:250px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;"/>
```

Na função, altere a opacidade para 1:

```
var loadFile = function(event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    output.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

Ou pode usar `visibility: hidden` e alterar na função para `visibility: visible`:

Na função:

```
var loadFile = function(event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    output.style.visibility= "visible";
}
```

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudou muito!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode deixar como padrão da imagem um caminho para uma imagem explicativa (algo como: "Selecione seu arquivo") ou até um gif 1x1 transparente.

Desta forma vai mostrar aquela imagem até que o usuário selecione a dele.

```
<img src="sem-imagem.jpg" id="output" style="width:100%;height:250px;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="file" name="img" id="img" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" onchange="loadFile(event)"/>
<br/><br/>
```

Ou até mesmo ocultar a imagem até que algo tenha sido selecionado, mas acho a primeira opção mais interessante.

Comment: Tentei fazer isto, porém acontece que isto ai é em laravel

Comment: e então nao ta aceitando quando tento colocar uma img

Comment: E Se colocar no javascript? quando iniciar o documento mudar o SRC da imagem?

Se não der certo acho que você terá que realmente ocultar a imagem, talvez com uma classe CSS e depois quando definir o SRC do output adicionar também ao output a classe que deixaria a imagem visivel ou apenas um display:block;. Entende o que quero dizer? Não sei se é possível no laravel fazer isso, tenho pouca experiência com ele.